# Objective c- only specific UILabel gets edited in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am new to Objective C .I have `UITableViewCell` using reuse identifiers. The `UILabel` taxRate is set in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Also when user click on the label `UIAlertController` gets opened and user can edit new taxRate. The problem is when user edits the taxRate, only the `UILabel` in last row gets changed. Any suggestions are welcome.

```
UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction

                 actionWithTitle:@"OK"

                 style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault

                 handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)

                 {   UITextField * textField = alert.textFields.firstObject;
                     taxRateGlobal = textField.text;

                         [taxRate setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tax %.01f",taxRateGlobal.floatValue],@"%"]];
                   }];



 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier1 = @"cellIdentifier1";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier1];
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier1];
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];

    //Add cell
    [self viewForCell:indexPath.row];


    //SET TEXT TO PRODUCT NAME ,TAX RATE ,UNIT AND RATE OF SELECTED PRODUCT
    if (tsSinltonObj.selectedProductArray.count) {
        ProductPARA *product=tsSinltonObj.selectedProductArray[indexPath.row];
        [productName setText:product.prod_name];
        [taxRate setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tax %.01f",[product.prod_tax_rate floatValue]],@"%"]];
        [unit setText:product.prod_unit];
        [rate setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",product.prod_rate]];

        taxRate.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture =
        [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(editTaxRate:)];
        [taxRate addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

        ProductPurchasedPARA *productInfo=tsSinltonObj.tPurchasedProductInfoArray[indexPath.row];


        [noFProduct setPlaceholder:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",productInfo.pClientProdAmount]];

        int xyz = [productInfo.pClientProdAmount intValue];
        if(xyz == 0)
        {
            [noFProduct setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"1"]];
        }
        else
        {
            [noFProduct setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",productInfo.pClientProdAmount]];
        }

        //IF PRODUCT AMOUNT IS ALREADY ENTERED BY CLIENT i.e THIS PAGE OPEN FOR UPDATING

        if (tsSinltonObj.tPurchasedProductInfoArray.count>indexPath.row) {
        //ROUND UP TOTAL

            NSString *totalCost=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[tsSinltonObj getCurrencyIdentifierTextFromServerClass],[tsSinltonObj tCommaFormatLogic:productInfo.pToatlCost ]];

            ProductPARA *obj=tsSinltonObj.selectedProductArray[indexPath.row];

            NSNumber *taxProd=obj.prod_tax_rate;
            NSNumber *total=@([[rate text]doubleValue] * [[noFProduct text]doubleValue]);
            NSNumber *taxPerProd=@(([taxProd doubleValue]/100)*[total doubleValue]);
            NSNumber *result=@([total doubleValue]+[taxPerProd doubleValue]);

            resultTemp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[tsSinltonObj getCurrencyIdentifierTextFromServerClass],[tsSinltonObj tCommaFormatLogic:result]];
            totalCost = resultTemp;
            productInfo.pToatlCost = result;

            tsSinltonObj.totalAmount=@([tsSinltonObj.totalAmount doubleValue] + [productInfo.pToatlCost doubleValue]);


            NSLog(@"total = %@",total);
            NSLog(@"taxperProd = %@", taxPerProd);
            NSLog(@"result = %@", result);
            NSLog(@"resultTemp = %@", resultTemp);

            NSRange searchResult = [resultTemp rangeOfString:@"."];
            if (searchResult.location == NSNotFound) {
                //IF SEARCH RESULT NOT FOUND
                [Total setText:resultTemp];
            } else {
                //ROUNDUP LOGIC
                NSString *roundupExponnt=[resultTemp substringFromIndex:searchResult.location+1];

                if (roundupExponnt.length>2) {
                    roundupExponnt=[resultTemp substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,2)];
                    resultTemp=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[resultTemp substringToIndex: searchResult.location],roundupExponnt];
                }
                [Total setText:resultTemp];

            }


        }else
        {
            Total.text=@"00.00";
            noFProduct.placeholder=@"1";
        }

        // create a perform request to call the didLoadRows method on the next event loop.
       [self performSelector:@selector(_tableViewDidLoadRows:) withObject:tableView afterDelay:0];

    }

[cell addSubview: cellView];
return cell;

}
```

[Click to open image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMPgv.png)

Comment: add code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Provide your cellForRowAtIndexPath code

Comment: Provide storyboard printscreen

Comment: I have done all the coding programmatically. So there's nothing on storyboard. But the output on simulator looks like the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
-(void)editTaxRate:(id)sender{

    UILabel *lbl = (UILabel *)sender;
    int arrayIndex = lbl.tag;

    //Your UIAlertController Code

    UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {

        UITextField * textField = alert.textFields.firstObject;
        taxRateGlobal = textField.text;
        ProductPARA *product=tsSinltonObj.selectedProductArray[arrayIndex];
        [product setProd_tax_rate:taxRateGlobal];
        [tableView reloadData];

    }];
    [alertController addAction:ok];

    //Show your Alert
}
```

Comment: It is not working. because as they are prototype cells created programmatically, `taxRate` label in every cell will have the same tag.

Comment: Please add taxRate.tag = indexPath.row in your cell for row at indexPath method. Look into my another answer. Another thing if you don't share your code properly I don't think anyone can help you.

Comment: Yes you do !! Voted Up

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are showing value from your array in your tableView so update your array when you edit your taxRate and call

`[tableView reloadData];`

You can keep track your array index by calling:

```
taxRate.tag = indexPath.row;
```

and then you will get your particular label in editTaxRate method if your method signature like this:

```
-(void)editTaxRate:(id)sender{
    UILable *lbl = (UILabel *)sender;
    int arrayIndex = lbl.tag
 }
```

And you can change the array value now. Hope this help. Please let me know if you have any question.

Comment: Please share your code editTaxRate and other methods which is related with tableView data showing.

Comment: In editTaxRate I have UIViewController only. And its Ok button action is posted in the question.

Comment: I think I have to apply some logic such that only specific row from tableView gets edited. Any suggestions?

Comment: But if you don't edit the array item it will back to previous taxrate again, maybe I need to tell you the whole mechanism. A bit busy now will update you soon.